# Wordpress 4.1 Plugin: "Rename wp-login.php" causes password protected pages to stop working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, password-protection

I have a custom built WordPress theme where the addition of the "**Rename wp-login.php**" Plugin has caused my password protected pages to stop working.

This is the built in "password protected page" function, not a additional plugin.

When I go to the page in question, I still see the form to enter the password, but upon entering a password, the page simply refreshes and does not display the hidden content that it should be.

I have tried changing the password, I have tried making the page NON-PASSWORD-PROTECTED, then changing it back.  Same thing, just a page refresh.  I'm having no luck on Google or WP.org finding an answer to this issue.  I am running WPMU Version 4.1.

Any and all help is appreciated.

**UPDATE 2/11/15**

First of all, this is an issue being caused by a plugin.  Apologies *`birgire`* because the ONE plugin I was not allowed to deactivate (for security purposes) is, in fact, the source of the problem.

The plugin is called: **Rename wp-login.php** and this plugin was implemented as we were experiencing an extremely high volume of bot net attacks on our standard "wp-login/wp-admin" pages respectively.

This plugin is not allowing the proper redirect to happen after the password field is submitted.  I will be contacting the plugin author directly but in the meantime, if anyone is in the same boat as I am (using this plugin) and has found a fix or work-around, I would love to hear it.

Thanks *`birgire`* and *`Leftium`* for the help so far.

Comment: Does it work on the default theme, without plugins?

Comment: nope!  Disabled all plugins.  Problem still exists.

Comment: ... so you're just using the WordPress password protection feature out of the box? Did you check your error logs? Maybe your install is corrupted? Also check if the `wp_postpass_***` cookie is created.

Comment: If the install were corrupted, wouldn't that affect the other 28 sites on the MU network?

Comment: We can't rule anything out yet ;-) Also check if you have any mu-plugins ("must use") activated that might affect this. I just checked this on my wpmu 4.1 install, and it seems to work as expected. Can you see if the  cookie was  created?

Comment: If I use "inspect element" in Chrome and select: Resources > Cookies, I can see that the "wp_postpass_***" cookie is NOT being created.  What should be done from here?  Thanks Birgire.

Comment: Additional information that might help: previous version of WP before upgrade, link to plugin + plugin version. The only "Rename wp-login.php" I could find says it is "unmaintained." Can you use another way to protect wp-login.php? Like .htaccess? (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6402/is-there-any-way-to-rename-or-hide-wp-login-php)

Comment: Thats the one Leftium.... the "unmaintained" one.  We were on Version 4.0.1 before the upgrade.  I'll look into the .htaccess option.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: @ben.kaminski Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm in the same exact situation right now.

Answer (score 1):

*Was just looking for this myself...*

1. Search for the text: `the_password_form`

   - This is the hook the theme uses to customize the password form.
   - It is probably in the `functions.php` file under your custom theme directory.
2. Inside this snippet of PHP, replace `wp-pass.php` with `wp-login.php?action=postpass`

   - `wp-pass` was deprecated in favor of `wp-login.php` since v3.4.

---

Sources and more detailed info:

- [Are your password protected posts and pages broken since upgrading to WordPress 3.4?](http://tummel.me/wordpress-3-4-custom-password-form/)
- [Customizing And Styling The Password Protected Form](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/customizing-and-styling-the-password-protected-form--wp-22375)

Comment: This is getting closer... Thanks Leftium.  Although, I can assure you that this function is not in my custom theme folder's functions.php file.  Is there a snippet I need to add to my functions.php to get this working?  This all worked great before the 4.1 upgrade.  If I need to add that hook to functions, I have no problem with it, but what exactly is the function I need to add that I never had to before?  I can't seem to find it in the Codex.

Comment: *** I just downloaded the "twenty fifteen" theme to check the functions.php for the snippet you mention, it does not exist there either ***

Comment: @ben.kaminski: Hooks are optional modifications to core WP functions. By convention, they are in functions.php, but they could be put in a different php file, too. If there are no hooks, the original `function get_the_password_form` is in the `wp-includes/post-template.php` file.